# I can't find object control in fluid simulation blender 2.82

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

In the older versions of blender the fluid physics had the option of making an object a 'control object' to manipulate the fluid flow with its shape. Now in 2.82 i can't find this option and i still haven't figured out a similar solution. Has this option changed location or name?

Comment: Hello :). Since 2.82. the old fluid simulation system is replaced with Mantaflow. However, I'm no expert on that :). You can [download Blender 2.81](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.81/) if you need the old system.

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to an effector object within the physics tab